# Como comparar el tiempo de un registro Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy queriendo calcular el tiempo que posee un cliente registrado, si el cliente posee menos de 3 meses desde su fecha de registro el cliente sigue activo, si el cliente posee mas de 3 meses y menos de 12 meses esta semiactivo, ¿me explico?, he intentado algunas ideas sin embargo no son infalibles, por ejemplo:

```
<% if time_ago_in_words(customer.date_of_issue) == "3 meses" %>
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Activo</span>
<% elsif customer.date_of_issue == "3 meses" && time_ago_in_words(customer.date_of_issue) < "6 meses" %>
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">Semi Activo</span>        
<% else time_ago_in_words(customer.date_of_issue) > "6 meses" %>
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">Inactivo</span>   
<% end %>
```

Sin embargo no es preciso ya que no se pueden comparar meses o dias, debido a que es una cadena de texto, por lo que solo lee los numeros de la cadena, se que hay una forma mas correcta de hacer esto, algo similar a:

```
<% if customer.date_of_issue == Date.new..3.months.ago %>Active<% else %>Older<%end %>
```

Sin embargo no logro hacerlo trabajar de forma correcta, agradezco toda su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario que conviertas a texto, puedes usar los [comparadores](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) del objeto `Time`:

```
[7] pry(main)> date_of_issue = 3.months.ago
=> Mon, 26 Aug 2019 21:37:14 UTC +00:00
[8] pry(main)> date_to_compare = date_of_issue - 1.minute
=> Mon, 26 Aug 2019 21:36:14 UTC +00:00
[9] pry(main)> date_of_issue > date_to_compare
=> true
[11] pry(main)> date_of_issue > date_to_compare + 1.minute
=> false
```

Esto, aplicado a tu problema, debería ser algo como:

```
  <% if customer.date_of_issue > 3.months.ago %>
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Activo</span>
  <% elsif customer.date_of_issue > 6.months.ago
    # O 1.year.ago, no lo tengo claro, ya que veo 2 definiciones distintas
    # en tu pregunta
  %> 
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">Semi Activo</span>        
  <% else %>
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">Inactivo</span>   
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Como comparar si la fecha de registro tiene menos de 3 meses Alter, hago lo siguiente pero no funciona: ´customer.date_of_issue < 3.months.ago´

Comment: @HectorHernandez es que me parece que la comparación la estás haciendo al revés. Revisa mi última actualización de la respuesta

Comment: Excelente Alter! Muy bien explicado =D Lo que sucedia que el ago me era confuso, por que comparaba al contrario utilizaba el menor que ( < ) cuando si te pones a pesar el ago invierte eso, en ese caso seria mayor ( > )